# SQLAlchemy : executing table based custom function

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to execute a postgresql custom function from SQLAlchemy. My function takes in input each row of the table and output a scalar value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION apply1(line mytable) RETURNS integer
```

In pure SQL, I'm calling this function with the command:

```
select apply1(mytable.*) from mytable;
```

I'm trying to generate this command with SQLAlchemy expressions, but with no success.

Example:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa 
s = sa.func.apply1(MyTable()).select()
```

Generated SQL

```
SELECT apply1() AS apply1_1 FROM train
```

I have tested several commands from SQLAlchemy user guide but with no success.
An important point: I have to use the SQLAlchemy expressions and not just generate the raw SQL command.

Does anybody have a good solution ?

Thanks !